# Got error in my python code "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [16, 8760]"

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-learn

I used python 2.7 and sklearn 1.8.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
```

then I created 2d array using 1d arrays.

```
x=np.array([a,b,c,d...])
```

like that (a,b,c,d.. are 1d arrays)

```
y=np.array(arr)
```

arr also 1d array

```
model = GaussianNB()
model.fit(x,y)
```

its give me a this error

```
    File "E:/python/read2.py", line 73, in <module>
    model.fit(x,y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 182, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 531, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 181, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [16, 8760]
```

x.shape => (16, 8760)
y.shape => (8760,)

please need help..

Comment: What does the help for `fit` say about the required shapes of the 2 inputs?  Do you understand the shapes of `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 0):

From: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.fit

```
X : array-like, shape (n_samples, n_features)
Training vectors, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.
y : array-like, shape (n_samples,)
```

Your values:

```
x.shape => (16, 8760) y.shape => (8760,)
```

which looks like 8760 samples, 16 features?  If so `x.T` might work.

Comment: thank you for your response,yes I read that and I know x shape is wrong that is why I explain how I created x.thank you.